# Size class for UISplitViewController on iPhone Plus in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, size-classes

It seems that there is a bug/feature with the way size classes work on a plus iPhone in landscape while using a `UISplitViewController`. There are two ways it can be displayed: Either the master controller on the left and detail on the right, or master is collapsed and detail takes up the whole screen. The problem is that in both cases the size class for detail seems to be wR hC. When master is visible, the detail is very small and there is no way it can be considered to have regular width.

I would expect the following behaviour:

- Master visible: Detail is wC hC
- Master collapsed: Detail is wR hC

Instead I get

- Master visible: Detail is wR hC
- Master collapsed: Detail is wR hC

Is this a feature? or a bug?